# (R) Alternate way for row sum, multiple columns with similar name

Tags: r, dplyr

So, i don't know if the title makes it easy to understand, but basically i want to change this to the minimum of code possible:

```
data %>% 
group_by(name) %>%
mutate(
    plataforma.3DS = sum(plataforma.3DS),
    plataforma.PS3 = sum(plataforma.PS3),
    plataforma.PS4 = sum(plataforma.PS4),
    plataforma.PSP = sum(plataforma.PSP),
    plataforma.PSV = sum(plataforma.PSV),
    plataforma.Wii = sum(plataforma.Wii),
    plataforma.WiiU = sum(plataforma.WiiU),
    plataforma.X360 = sum(plataforma.X360),
    plataforma.XOne = sum(plataforma.XOne)   
)
```

I have some other columns that i need to do this, so how can i reduce my code? thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to tell without seeing the structure of your data frame. From the context, I think it is very likely that you're looking for `pivot_longet()` to get `plataforma` as column, then you want to `group_by()` it and `summarize()` with sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify it with `across`. Note that `mutate` replaces the column value with the `sum` of that column.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('plataforma'), sum))
```

It the intention is to return a single sum per each column, change the `mutate` to `summarise`

```
data %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with('plataforma'), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

NOTE: The title specified row sum, while the code showed in OP's post is doing column sum.

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueRodrigues Yes, you can create new columns by specifying `.names = "{.col}_new"` in `mutate/summarise` `across`

Comment: like a charm, thanks! by the way, can i do something similar to create some columns? Mine is like:

`data %>% mutate(
    plataforma.3DS = str_detect(plataforma, regex("3DS", ignore_case = T)),
    plataforma.PS3 = str_detect(plataforma, regex("PS3", ignore_case = T)),
    plataforma.PS4 = str_detect(plataforma, regex("PS4", ignore_case = T))
    plataforma.PSV = str_detect(plataforma, regex("PSV", ignore_case = T))
)`
I'm trying to find something using `help(across)`, but no sucess

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueRodrigues I guess you are doing this on the same column right?

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueRodrigues If it is on the same column, do `map_dfc(c("3DS", "PS3", ...), ~ data %>% transmute(!! str_c('plataforma\\.', .x) := str_detect(plataforma, regex(.x, ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>% bind_cols(data, .)`

Comment: i'm getting this: `Error: Input must be a vector, not a function.`. 
Can you help?

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueRodrigues have you changed the `...` to actual values.   i.e. `map(c("3DS", "PS3"), ~ data %>% transmute(!! str_c('plataforma.", .x) := str_detect(plataforma, regex(.x, ignore_case = TRUE))))` can you test if this returns error

Comment: yes, i tried with c(...) and also storing the values, neither of them works

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueRodrigues you meant, it is not returning output or is there an error

Comment: still getting error message

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueRodrigues let me show an example that can be reproduced. i.e. `

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueRodrigues this works, `data <- data.frame(plataforma = c('3DS_45', 'PS35', '2DS', '42_3DS')); out <- map_dfc(c("3DS", "PS3"), ~ data %>% transmute(!! str_c('plataforma.', .x) := str_detect(plataforma, regex(.x, ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>% bind_cols(data, .)` and checking `dim(out)#
[1] 4 3`

Comment: many thanks my friend!